# R: Weird behaviour consistent with R specification?

Tags: r

I observe the following, and seemingly inconsistent, behaviour when working with large lists with named fields:

```
> L[[regionID]][203]
$`112175100`
[1] 0

> L[[regionID]][["112175100"]]
[1] 93.98552
```

and also

```
> Reduce("+", L[[regionID]])
[1] 434005.8

> S <- 0
> for(n in names(L[[regionID]]))
+ {
+     S <- S + L[[regionID]][[n]]
+ }
> S
[1] 458813.5
```

Can anyone tell me whether the observed output is consistent with the language specification?

Comment: Probably not, unless you provide a reproducible example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Fair enough - my question was not well-posed. It seems to me that the output I posted is not consistent with the R language specification, and I want to know whether this is true.

Comment: Your output looks fishy to me too.  What are the results of  `dput(L[[regionID]][203])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might have multiple elements with the same name,

```
L <- list()
regionID <- 1

L[[regionID]] <- list("112175100" = 0, "112175100" = 93.98552)

L[[regionID]][2]
L[[regionID]][["112175100"]]
```

Comment: Good call,  `identical(length(names(x)), length(unique(names(x))))` might be a way to check that.

Comment: or `x[names=="112175100"]`

Comment: This explains the first expected behaviour, but not the second - if anything the Reduce function should sum up more elements in case there are identical labels, not less.

Comment: Yes, everything is either positive or zero

Comment: this guessing game is going nowhere, provide data if you want a real answer